# PHP email piping error

Tags: php, email, piping

I'm writing a php script to pipe email from a forward in my CPanel. I have found this script on the internet; I am trying to parse the email and send it back to myself for testing, but it instead returns this error:

```
The following text was generated during the delivery attempt:

------ pipe to |/home1/<account>/pipe.php
 generated by pipe@example.com ------

Error in argument 1, char 3: option not found <
Usage: php [-q] [-h] [-s] [-v] [-i] [-f <file>]
 php <file> [args...]
 -a Run interactively
 -b <address:port>|<port> Bind Path for external FASTCGI Server mode
 -C Do not chdir to the script's directory
 -c <path>|<file> Look for php.ini file in this directory
 -n No php.ini file will be used
 -d foo[=bar] Define INI entry foo with value 'bar'
 -e Generate extended information for debugger/profiler
 -f <file> Parse <file>. Implies `-q'
 -h This help
 -i PHP information
 -l Syntax check only (lint)
 -m Show compiled in modules
 -q Quiet-mode. Suppress HTTP Header output.
 -s Display colour syntax highlighted source.
 -v Version number
 -w Display source with stripped comments and whitespace.
 -z <file> Load Zend extension <file>.
 -T <count> Measure execution time of script repeated <count> times.

------ This is a copy of the message, including all the headers. ------
```

The script is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/php -q
<?
$fd = fopen("php://stdin", "r");
$email = "";
while (!feof($fd)) {
    $email .= fread($fd, 1024);
}
fclose($fd);

//split the string into array of strings, each of the string represents a single line, received
$lines = explode("\n", $email_content);

// initialize variable which will assigned later on
$from = "";
$subject = "";
$headers = "";
$message = "";
$is_header = true;

//loop through each line
for ($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i++) {
    if ($is_header) {
        // hear information. instead of main message body, all other information are here.
        $headers .= $lines[$i]."\n";

        // Split out the subject portion
        if (preg_match("/^Subject: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $subject = $matches[1];
        }
        //Split out the sender information portion
        if (preg_match("/^From: (.*)/", $lines[$i], $matches)) {
            $from = $matches[1];
        }
    } else {
        // content/main message body information
        $message .= $lines[$i]."\n";
    }
    if (trim($lines[$i])=="") {
        // empty line, header section has ended
        $is_header = false;
    }
}

mail("email@example.com", $subject, '"' . $message . . "\n\n\n" . $email . '"');
```

The permissions for the php file are 755.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried changing your second line to

```
<?php
```

also make sure there's no extra spaces in first line